# Should one forward declare classes from a namespaced library?

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

I'm designing a C++ library that will be placed inside a namespace.

If the users of my library only need a forward declaration of one of my classes and since you can't do forward declarations of things inside a namespace, e.g. `class ns_name::class_name;`, should I

- tell them to include the whole header file that contains that class instead,
- or, provide them with a way to forward declare stuff from my library? For example:

  ```
  #define MD_FORWARD_DECLARE(x) namespace md { x; }
  ```

  Which could then be used like this:

  ```
  MD_FORWARD_DECLARE(class foo)
  ```

  Is it worth it?
- Or, just let them do `namespace md { class foo; }` themselves?
- Or, as mentioned by [DevSolar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60281/devsolar), make a dedicated header file consisting of forward declarations, like `<iosfwd>`? This seems most elegant to me.

Comment: Let them do what they want. The macro doesn't seem very useful to me.

Comment: You cannot forward-declare something in a namespace? `<iosfwd>` makes me think you actually can...

Comment: @DevSolar That's a great idea. How didn't I know about `<iosfwd>` before… I'll add it to my question as the fourth choice.

Comment: Option 3. `namespace md { class foo; }` *is* a forward declaration of a thing inside a namespace.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, but it looks awkward, as if you were adding new content to a namespace that's not yours. I personally find the macro solution more appealing than that.

Comment: The third option leaves the choice to the user, which isn't bad in my opinion. However, if you'd like to provide something, the dedicated header seems most elegant to me.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You build a library. This will ship with a header file that clients will include if developing software using your library. That header is *part* of your library. *You* code and ship it. If it does `namespace md { class foo; }`, that's perfectly normal and nothing that would make a C++ coder blink even once. If you ship your library *without* a header and expect people to do their own declarations, *that* would make me blink twice (and then discard your library)...

Comment: @user2079303 "Let them do what they want." is not a very good design principle IMO. It causes inconsistency and contradicts "there should be one — and preferably only one — obvious way to do it"; I don't want my clients to waste time picking their preferred way from multiple choices.

Comment: @zenith IMO, *not* letting them do what they want will cause inconsistency. If you let users do what they want, they can comply to the conventions that they use everywhere else in their code that does not use your library. If you don't let them do what they want, you force them to possibly break those conventions.

Comment: @zenith technically there still is only one way to forward declare the class (option 3) unless you provide that (awkward IMO) macro in which case there is two ways. You cannot avoid contradicting the guideline you quoted when doing one thing (include definitions) does one thing (declares the class) in addition to doing more.

Comment: @user2079303 I meant inconsistency in usage of the lib _between different projects_. Of course it can't be fully prevented but I think it should be minimized as far as sensibly possible. Option 3 (and by extension option 2) is off-putting because it is inconsistent with the standard library where you can't forward declare stuff from `std`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @molbdnilo pointed out, there is nothing wrong with forward declaring with namespace. First option is not an option at all, for various reasons I dont want to include header until I have to, forward declaration is always preferred way.
Why dont you just provide a header with forward declarations as many boost implementations do? for example boost spirit numerics_fwd.hpp?

Ah, missed @DevSolar comment. IMHO this is the best solution.

Comment: I'll probably go the STL way, i.e. include whole header instead of forward-declaration. If compilation times become a problem, I'll make something like `<numerics_fwd.hpp>`.